# SpringBoot EventListener don't receive events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-listener

my `EventListener` annotation don't receive any Spring Event. Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class ProxyConfig {

    public ProxyConfig() {
        System.out.println("I can see this in the console");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("WON'T WORK :-(");  // FIXME
    }

    @EventListener
    public void test(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("WON'T WORK :-(");  // FIXME
    }
}
```

And here is my `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

According to https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2 and https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/annotation-driven-event-listeners-in-spring-4-2/ it must be working, but it still not print my "WON'T WORK :-(" String :(

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What packages are `Application` and `ProxyConfig` in?

Comment: `Application` is in package `com.mycompany.app`. And `ProxyConfig` is in a subpacke: `com.mycompany.app.configuration.impl`

Comment: By creating a `META-INF/spring.factories`file (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) it works without the Annotations, but not with... :(

Comment: I've just noticed the events that you're listening for. That's expected behaviour. I've tried to explain what's going on in my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two events that you are listening for are both published very early in an application's lifecycle.

`ApplicationStartedEvent` is sent "as early as conceivably possible as soon as a SpringApplication has been started - before the Environment or ApplicationContext is available, but after the ApplicationListeners have been registered".

`ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` is published "when a SpringApplication is starting up and the Environment is first available for inspection and modification."

In both cases, the event is published too early for a listener to be found via annotations and the application context. As you've observed you can use `spring.factories` to register your listener. Alternatively, you can use the setter method on `SpringApplication`.

Comment: How to achieve it via SpringApplication setter?

Comment: Can try with `ApplicationReadyEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but anyway, to anyone having the same issue...

I've just wasted a few hours with the exact same problem, I've searched the internet and did countless tests to no avail, I've tried annotating with `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` and `@PostConstruct`, nothing worked.

My philosophy is that when something simple doesn't work and the internet doesn't help, it means you messed up something. So I started reviewing my code and I see you've made the same mistake as me.

You've copied the example from somewhere else or changed the original configuration class from `MyApp` to `Application`, and you've forgotten to change the line:

```
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
```

to

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

The first line will do nothing, unless `MyApp` also has `@SpringBootApplication` or other configuration annotations, the second one will find the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and will properly start the Spring Boot application.

By the way, both `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` and `@PostConstruct` work just fine, tested on **Java 17**.